# Rails 3 - Mock/Stub - Testing Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

i have a question about testing following line of Rails code:

https://gist.github.com/1289849

in my test code i have something like this(obviously don't works):

https://gist.github.com/1289848

Someone can help me write right  test code  for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To make testing it easier, you should move this logic to a class method on your Client model. I'm also assuming you have a `has_many :clients` on your user model, which is what your query is implying.

Something like:

```
class Client
  def self.search_by_name(name)
    all.where("name LIKE %?%", name).order("name ASC")
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
@clients = current_user.clients.search_by_name(params[:search])
```

This will allow you to test in a unit test, rather than with an integration test.

client_spec.rb:

```
describe Client, 'searching by name' do
  let(:current_user) { User.create!(...) }
  let!(:client) { Client.create!(:name => 'client name', :user => current_user) }

  it 'should find the clients by name' do
    Client.search_by_name('client name').should include(client)
  end
end
```

Then your integration test could just stub the `search_by_name` method and return a collection of mocks, making it easier to test.